# In Ruby trying to use .each do on a given hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, hash, control-flow

This is what I am attempting to do:

Write a method that takes the hash and prints if city is large (more than 100,000) or small (otherwise). Printing something like: Vancouver is a large city.

Here is my provided hash:

```
bc_cities_population = {vancouver: 2135201, victoria:  316327, abbotsford: 149855, kelowna: 141767, nanaimo:  88799, white_rock: 82368, kamloops: 73472, chilliwack: 66382 }
```

Here is my code:

```
bc_cities_population = {vancouver: 2135201, victoria:  316327, abbotsford: 149855, kelowna: 141767, nanaimo:  88799, white_rock: 82368, kamloops: 73472, chilliwack: 66382 }

bc_cities_population.each do |city, population|  
if population > 100,000
  puts "#{city} is a big ol city!"
elsif 
  puts "#{city}city is a tiny ol town"
  end
end
```

Thanks for your help..

Edit: Here is the error I am receiving..

```
 ruby big_small_city.rb
big_small_city.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...er: 2135201, victoria:  316327, abbotsford: 149855, kelowna...
```

Edit2:

this is my revised code which i am still unsure why is not working..

```
bc_cities_population = {vancouver: 2135201, victoria:  316327, abbotsford: 149855, kelowna: 141767, nanaimo:  88799, white_rock: 82368, kamloops: 73472, chilliwack: 66382 }

bc_cities_population.each do |city, population|  
  if population > 100_000
    puts "#{city} is a big ol city!"
  else
    puts "#{city} is a tiny ol town"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write

```
bc_cities_population = {vancouver: 2135201, victoria:  316327, abbotsford: 149855, kelowna: 141767, nanaimo:  88799, white_rock: 82368, kamloops: 73472, chilliwack: 66382 }

bc_cities_population.each do |city, population|  
  if population > 100_000
    puts "#{city} is a big ol city!"
  else
    puts "#{city}city is a tiny ol town"
  end
end
```

Lets run it :

```
Arup-iMac:arup_ruby$ ruby test.rb
vancouver is a big ol city!
victoria is a big ol city!
abbotsford is a big ol city!
kelowna is a big ol city!
nanaimocity is a tiny ol town
white_rockcity is a tiny ol town
kamloopscity is a tiny ol town
chilliwackcity is a tiny ol town
Arup-iMac:arup_ruby$
```

The wring you did is - `if population > 100,000` - `100,000` is not a valid representation of a number to a computer. You could write it as `100000` instead of `100_000`. But [any number of underscore characters (_)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html) can appear anywhere between digits in a numerical literal. This feature enables you, for example, to separate groups of digits in numeric literals, which can *improve the readability of your code*.

Comment: `elsif` without condition? It should be `else`.

Comment: @MarekLipka That's a quick copy/paste typo.

Comment: Sure - I just wanted to improve this answer.

Comment: BTW `1_00_000` looks ugly and unconsistent, `100_000` is much better.

Comment: @MarekLipka Humm.. _improved_ again. :)

Comment: i edited my code like so and recieved the same error, however when i copy and paste yours it works fine! i will post my code in the edit

Comment: @BrandynPrasad impossible. Did you save your file after first edition?

Comment: @Marek Lipka quite sure i did!

Comment: @Marek Lipka 

syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...er: 2135201, victoria:  316327, abbotsford: 149855, kelowna...
...                               ^

Comment: @BrandynPrasad Your Ruby version?? do `ruby -v` in your terminal and tell us.

Comment: @BrandynPrasad is your copied snippet an entire file content?

Comment: indeed it is @MarekLipka

Comment: @BrandynPrasad May be there is a junk character inserted in your editor during copy/paste from this SO web answer... delete the whole content(select all content and delete everything from the file, and save it) and re-type it manually again, save and run it.

Comment: @ArupRakshit very strange though as when I copied your answer directly it works fine.. however when i edited my code by hand i still got the same error. i will try to replicate my code without any copy and paste once more. hopefully that does the trick.. but i don't really see what i did wrong!

Comment: I wrote everything out again from scratch and it now works! 

thanks for your efforts @MarekLipka and Arup!